# SQL count(max())

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a count of the largest issuer in my quer using Microsoft SQl Server Management Studio. In this case I want it to count the number of instances the largest `ISSUER_COUNTRY` occurs, which in this case would be `6` with the largest issuer being `US`.

```sql
    Declare @T as varchar(10) ='2019-08-01', @PortfolioID as Varchar(10)='B4'
    ;
    select [value_date], [SHORT_DESCRIPTON], [SM_SEC_GROUP],[ULT_ISSUER_NAME], [ISSUER_COUNTRY] 
    from [DATABASE]
    where [value_date] in (@T) 
    and  PORTF_LIST=@portfolioID
    and [SM_SEC_GROUP] in ('IBND','BND')
```

[image: A snippet of the query.]

```
value_date  SHORT_DESCRIPTON    SM_SEC_GROUP    PORTF_LIST  ULT_ISSUER_NAME ISSUER_COUNTRY
2019-08-01  ITALY (REPUBLIC OF)        RegS BND B4  ITALY (REPUBLIC OF) IT
2019-08-01  GERMANY (FEDERAL REPUBLIC OF) RegS  BND B4  GERMANY (FEDERAL REPUBLIC OF)   DE
2019-08-01  TREASURY NOTE   BND B4  UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    US
2019-08-01  TREASURY NOTE   BND B4  UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    US
2019-08-01  GERMANY (FEDERAL REPUBLIC OF) RegS  BND B4  GERMANY (FEDERAL REPUBLIC OF)   DE
2019-08-01  ITALY (REPUBLIC OF)        RegS BND B4  ITALY (REPUBLIC OF) IT
2019-08-01  FRANCE (REPUBLIC OF)       RegS BND B4  FRANCE (REPUBLIC OF)    FR
2019-08-01  SPAIN (KINGDOM OF)  BND B4  SPAIN (KINGDOM OF)  ES
2019-08-01  SPAIN (KINGDOM OF)  BND B4  SPAIN (KINGDOM OF)  ES
2019-08-01  TREASURY NOTE   BND B4  UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    US
2019-08-01  TREASURY NOTE   BND B4  UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    US
2019-08-01  TREASURY NOTE   BND B4  UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    US
2019-08-01  TREASURY NOTE   BND B4  UNITED STATES OF AMERICA    US
```

Comment: Most people here want sample data _and expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: The way you describe the query you probably mean the MAXimum COUNT, not the COUNT of MAXimums

Comment: @jarlh How do I easily format it as a table?

Comment: Write your data in proper columns. Put an empty row before, and 4 <space> first in each row. (Or mark the data and click `{}`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want `top (1)` and `group by`:

```
select top (1) [ISSUER_COUNTRY], count(*)
from [DATABASE]
where [value_date] in (@T) and
      PORTF_LIST = @portfolioID  and
      [SM_SEC_GROUP] in ('IBND', 'BND')
group by ISSUER_COUNTRY
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want multiple rows in the event of ties, then use `top (1) with ties`.

Comment: I cant edit as its less than 6 characters, but you are missing an "and" after @portfolioID

Comment: @GordonLinoff How would I change the code to count for each date for multiple dates? I.e. get the top 1 for every day in a given time span. I would use `Declare @T_1 as varchar(10) ='2019-07-01'` as my second date as an example

Comment: @BlackBear . . . That would be a different question.  If merely adding the date to the group by doesn't do what you want, then you should ask it as a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.